# Supersized - Read a specific value from a multilevel array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, slideshow

I have a JavaScript slideshow that reads pictures from a folder and I need to read the description of each picture from a .dat file.
This is the script:

```
    <?php

    require ('macoola.inc');
    $upload = new images_upload('installations/', 3000000, 'info.dat');
    $photo_list = $upload->read_data(); #this gets unserialized values from info.dat

#read all jpegs in the folder
    $path_userspecific_array = explode(";", $_SESSION['userDirs']);
    $images_splice = null;
    settype($images_splice, "array");
    foreach($path_userspecific_array as $thisdir){ 
    $thispath = ('installations/' . $thisdir);
    $thisimages = null;
    $thisimages = glob($thispath.'/{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.jpeg,*.JPEG}', GLOB_BRACE);
    $images_splice = array_merge($images_splice, $thisimages);
    }
    ?>
```

Then here the java:

```
 {
    image: '<?php
    echo $filename ?>',
    title: '<?php   
    **#show description here**
    ?>',
thumb : '<?php                                                                      echo $filename                                                                          ?>'
                                                                 }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem! Solution was extreamely easy.
Instead of using another script to read images in the folder I did extract links of the pictures and descriptions directly from .dat file like following code shows:

```
<?php

require ('macoola.inc');
$upload = new images_upload('url/', 3000000, 'info.dat');
$photo_list = $upload->read_data();
$photo_url = "url/";

?>
```

And then print the string I needed with foreach function to put into "slides" field in Supersized:

```
<?php                                            
foreach ($photo_list as $key=>$val){
$input .= " image: '".$photo_url.$key."', title: '".$val['desc']."', thumb : '',";
?> 
                                                        { <?php echo $input; ?> },
<?php } ?>
```